# What is this font from Monokai's atom package

Tags: fonts

Simple question  : do you know [this font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlaFd.png) ?
Extract from : https://atom.io/themes/monokai

I already searched on identifont.com but without success

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a Chrome Extension called WhatFont, I think you should check it out :)

Comment: This is a screenshot and the extension does not support it

Comment: But it look nearly to Monospaced I thnk

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found it : https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro

Viva GoogleFont